# How to move a gmail thread (email) to the archive folder? (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, gmail-api

From searching around I belive that the answer is to remove the INBOX label from the thread and that should do it but Im not sure if thats correct and Im not sure how to do that either, after spending hourse trying to figure out how. This is what I have so far to query threads

```
- (void)fetchThreads{

    self.output1.text = @"\n Getting threads...";
    GTLRGmailQuery_UsersThreadsList *query = [GTLRGmailQuery_UsersThreadsList queryWithUserId:@"me"];

    query.q = @"in:inbox";
    query.userId = @"me";
    self.service.shouldFetchNextPages = true;
    [self.service executeQuery:query delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket2:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

Comment: According to Managing POP and IMAP docs, you can configure the disposition of messages retrieved via POP with the [disposition property](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/pop_imap_settings#message_disposition). Check the [Users.settings: updatePop](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updatePop) method which allows you to use the disposition property. disposition property can accept 'archive' value which archives the message.

Comment: I believe OP is using the Gmail API, not POP or IMAP.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail does not have an "archive" folder, per se, but as you note:  removing the INBOX label will remove the message from the standard inbox views.

This is done using the `Users.messages.modify` operation, with the `removeLabelIds` argument as INBOX.

See this page, which includes examples:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify